# why single connection to redis perform bad and how to make it faster

Tags: c, performance, networking, redis, benchmarking

I am benchmarking redis recently and here is the result I got:

```
ubuntu 13.10 x86_64 with kernel version 3.11, 
Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 430 @ 2.27GHz × 4
8GB Memory
```

[image]

So given the same load, multiple connection to redis could perform 8x faster than single connection. I am not considering pipelining here, and I already tried many optimization approach in my test. (using taskset to make redis running in single core, using unix domain socket)

Two questions:

1. Why multiple connection to redis could perform this faster than single connection?
2. Is there any other way(other than pipeline) to improve performance under single connection?

Comment: I'd be suspicious of that first test run. I've had, in several cases beyond redis, concurrent access to UD sockets error out. Unfortunately, the Redis-benchmark tool doesn't seem to take errors into account. As such that test may not be showing you a rate for successful commands only.

Comment: I did some test using normal socket before and the result is almost the same. Multiple connection case could run must faster than single connection case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some performance testing for this problem these days and got some results here.

The key is to figure out where the extra latency comes from for the single connection case. My first hypophsis is they come from epoll. To find out that, I use [systemtap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) and the [script to determine epoll latency](https://github.com/openresty/stapxx#epoll-loop-blocking-distr). The result (above: 1 connection result, below: 10 connection result. Sorry, the unit should be **nanoseconds** in the pic):

[image]

From the result, you can see that the avg time staying in epoll is almost same, 8655 nanoseconds vs 10254 nanoseconds. However, there is a significant difference of total number. For 10 connection we call epoll wait 444528 times but  we will call it 2000054 times in single connection case, which is 4x and that's what lead to this additional time usage.

Next question would be why we call epoll so less time during multipe connection. After exploring a little bit with redis source code, I found the reason. Everytime epoll returns, it will return the number of events it gonna handle. The presudo code is like (hiding most of the details):

```
fds = epoll_wait(fds_we_are_monitoring);
for fd in fds:
    handle_event_happening_in(fd);
```

The return value `fds` is a collection of all the events in which IO is happening, for example, read input from socket. For single connection benchmark,  `fds_we_are_monitoring` is 1, since there are only one connection, then every time #fd would be 1. But for 10 connection case, `fds` could return any number less than 10, and then handling the events together in the `for loop`. The more events we get from epoll return once at a time, the faster we can get. Because the total number of requests is fixed, in this case, 1M set requests.

To verify that, I use systemtap to draw the distribution of return values of the function. [aeProcessEvents](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/ae.c#L352), which returns the number of events it handled.

[image]

We can see the avg: 1 in single connection case vs 7 in 10 connection case. Which proves our hypothesis that the more number of events epoll returns once, the faster we can handle the requests, until it become CPU bound.

I think I got the answer for the first question: Why multiple connection to redis could perform this faster than single connection. However, I am still wondering if there is any other way(other than pipeline) to improve performance under single connection. I would appreciate if anyone else could share some thinking about this.