# Why the performance of epoll_wait handling multiple fd's is faster than handling one fd

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have read somewhere that if epoll_wait call, gets multiple fd's to handle: epoll_wait(fds_we_are_monitoring), it is faster than in the case where fds_we_are_monitoring is one. I wonder why is that?

I am trying to see if epoll_wait impacts a latency in case of multiple connections as opposed to one.

Comment: Seems unlikely.  Show the source for this claim.

Comment: Seems like a bogus claim to me. Using epoll on multiple FDs is definitely faster than issuing an equivalent syscall on each one of them, but that's about it. Would be interesting if you could link to a source for this information.

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978981/why-single-connection-to-redis-perform-bad-and-how-to-make-it-faster

Comment: Why is it surprising that 10 parallel clients is faster than 1?

Comment: @stark In my case I'm sending one request only and the latency is increased when I decreased the amount of the connections

Comment: The question you refer to is specifically about **redis**. And [the self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016509/3440745) contains more detailed explorations: "From the result, you can see that the avg time staying in epoll is almost same, 8655 nanoseconds vs 10254 nanoseconds. However, there is a significant difference of total number. For 10 connection we call epoll wait 444528 times but we will call it 2000054 times in single connection case, which is 4x and that's what lead to this additional time usage."

Comment: Ok. The story is like that....

Comment: @stark Ok. The story is like that.... I have my own service which sends a request to aws elastic cache (redis). If Im using 4 cores on the machine that sends the request to redis, the latency for this request is 2ms. If Im using one core, the latency is 60ms. I know that whenever a core is added, the amount of connections to redis increased. So im trying to understand if there is a relationship between number of connections to latency. And this is how I got to the post I sent its link earlier.